# find a recursive relation for the characteristic polynomial of the $k \times k $ matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

find a recursive relation for the characteristic polynomial of the $k \times k $ matrix $$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 \\ \mbox{ } &  1 & . & . \\ \mbox{ } &\mbox{ } & . & . &. & \mbox{ } \\ \mbox{ } &\mbox{ } &\mbox{ } & . & . & 1 \\ \mbox{ } & \mbox{ } & \mbox{ } & \mbox{ } & 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$

and  compute  the polynomial for  $k\le 5$

My attempt : Let $M_k$ be the $k\times k$ matrix and $P_k(x)=\det(M_k-xI_k)$ be its characteristic polynomial. We have

$$P_k(x)=\det\begin{pmatrix} -x & 1 \\ 1 & -x & 1 \\ \mbox{ } & 1 & \ddots & \ddots \\ \mbox{ } &\mbox{ } & \ddots & . &. & \mbox{ } \\ \mbox{ } &\mbox{ } &\mbox{ } & . & . & 1 \\ \mbox{ } & \mbox{ } & \mbox{ } & \mbox{ } & 1 & -x\end{pmatrix}$$

after that im not  able  proceed  further

Any hints/solution will be appreciated

Comment: do it first for $k=2$ and $k=3. \;$  I found a quote "There is nothing impossible to him who will try."

Comment: ya  ,,,im  trying  @WillJagy.....haa

Comment: what do you get for $k=2?$

Comment: $x^2-1$ @WillJagy

Comment: now do $k=3.$ By the way, there is a pretty good recipe for writing the char poly in dimension 3, where $\sigma_1$ is the trace and $\sigma_3$ is the determinant, we also need $\sigma_2$ which is the sum of the little 2 by 2 prinipal minor determintns, Then char poly is $x^3 - \sigma_1 x^2 + \sigma_2 x - \sigma_3.$ I think there is also a recipe for $\sigma_2$ involving traces of the matrix squared, I will see if I can find that. Worth getting right and memorizing for dimension 2 and 3

Comment: Alright, worked it out, for matrix $M,$ $$\sigma_2 = \frac{1}{2} \left( \sigma_1^2 - \operatorname{trace}  M^2 \right)$$  where $\sigma_1 = \operatorname{trace}  M$ as i indicated

Comment: @WillJagy I'm not sure I believe your quote, but the converse is true: "There is nothing possible to him who will not try."

Comment: @jasmine Have you heard of the method of [determinant expansion by minors](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DeterminantExpansionbyMinors.html)?

Comment: @bof it is from the profile of the person who asked the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Look at the formula for the determinant of using the first row.
Then you get a recursive definition for the determinant.

Solution:

> $P_k(x)=-xP_{k-1}(x)-P_{k-1}(-1)$